# React Native ListView refresh indicator not showing at first loading in iOS

Tags: ios, listview, react-native, refresh

I'm using React Native 0.33.1 and I use a ListView with Refreshcontrol to indicate that the data is being loaded. The problem is on iOS, that if the ListView datasource is empty the loading indicator is not showing, so the user doesn't see that the data is being loaded. But if the ListView is not empty everything works fine. Also there are no problems on Android even with en empty ListView.
I tried to replace the whole ListView with a Loading indicator if there is no data, but then when the data is loaded, the top of the ListView is not aligned correctly and is behind the Navigationbar of the NavigatorIOS I am using.
Here's my Code for the render method and the loading at the beginning:

```
render(){
    return <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column', backgroundColor:'#FFF'}}>
     <ListView
        refreshControl={ <RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.refreshing} onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)} /> }
        style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column'}}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
        renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}>
      </ListView>
    </View>
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.unmounting = false;
    this.loadData();
}

loadData(){
    this.setState({refreshing:true});
    //Code to fetch data async
    .then((result) => {
      this.setState({refreshing:false, result:result});
    });
}
```